# Creating RDF for 2 related tables and run SPARQL query on them

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

Following are my 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Tree (
    "id"            integer NOT NULL,   -- Primary key
    "tags"          varchar(500),
    "rootNode"      integer NOT NULL    -- Referes to Node table's "id"
);
CREATE TABLE Node (
    "id"            integer NOT NULL,   -- Primary key
    "parent"        integer NOT NULL,
    "owner"         varchar(500),
    "data"          varchar(500),
    "tags"          varchar(500)
);
```

The common RDF file that I have created for these is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:wp="http://example.com/dm#">
    <wp:WPS rdf:about="http://example.com/">
    <wp:node><rdf:Description>  <wp:id>0</wp:id><wp:parent>-1</wp:parent><wp:owner>Kumar</wp:owner><wp:data>--#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#--</wp:data><wp:tags>MyTag</wp:tags></rdf:Description></wp:node>
    .....
    <wp:tree><rdf:Description>  <wp:treeId>814</wp:treeId><wp:treeTags>Banking</wp:treeTags><wp:rootNode>19989</wp:rootNode></rdf:Description></wp:tree>
    .......
</wp:WPS></rdf:RDF>
```

Is this correct way of creating a combined rdf file for these 2 tables?

---

Now I want to run SPQRQL query similar to following SQL query:

```
select w.id, w.tags, w.owner from Node w, Tree t where t.id=100;
```

I tried using following query using FILTER but could not get the desired result. What is the correct way to do this?

```
    PREFIX wp: <http://example.com/dm#> 
              SELECT ?x ?id 
              WHERE { 
                ?x wp:id ?id .
                ?x wp:trailId ?trailId .
                ?x wp:rootWP ?rootWP .
                FILTER (?trailId = 100)
                FILTER (?rootWP = ?id)
              }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you creating your own relational database schema? Why don't you use Jena's SDB implementation? You tagged the question with 'Jena', so I assumer you are using the API?

Comment: The relationall db schema is to show my data and relation between them in the form of 2 tables, and based on that I have created my RDF file.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood. It sounded like you created a schema so you could create RDF, not that the schema already existed.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you should not create database table structures yourself for storing RDF triples. It's a complex thing to get right, and even more difficult to make it performant. If you just want to create a persistent triple store, use the built-in capabilities of your RDF platform. In the case of Jena, this would be [TDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/index.html) or [SDB](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/sdb/index.html).

Alternatively, if you need to have your data stored in a relational schema, but you *also* want to see that data as RDF triples so that you can query it with SPARQL, you need a relational-to-RDF mapping tool. There is [standardisation work in this area](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-r2rml-20110324/), and open-source implementations such as [D2RQ](http://d2rq.org/)

Comment: I am not quite clear with statement `you should not create database table structures yourself for storing RDF triples`. I want to persist my data in TDB and as per my understanding, I need to have a RDF file for that, so for my case I initially created 2 rdf files for `Tree` and `Node`. And as these 2 files had relationship which I showed in my relational schema, so I created a single rdf file and persist that in TDB model. And now trying to query(sparql) them. If I am doing wrong what should I be doing?

Comment: TDB does not use a relational store (ie database) at all. Both TDB and SDB will initialise the storage layer for you, in TDB's case by creating b-tree index files on disk. Initialization is automatic the first time you open an uninitialised store. Other than that, I don't understand the question. Creating RDF does not require you to define SQL tables.

Comment: So you are using a relational schema just to *document* the RDF concepts you are designing? I guess you can do that, but it's very unusual. More normally you would consider the RDFS or OWL classes in the data model, and the properties that connect those classes. Some people use UML diagrams to document the relationships, but personally I've never found those very useful.

Comment: Thanks for this information @Ian, I will look at RDFS & OWL. By your comments do you mean that even if we know the relationship beforehand we should not try to put them up in our RDFs? And whatever join that we want to apply should be through query? NOTE: I have also updated my question with sparql query that I used.

Comment: This is getting to be a complicated question to discuss in a StackOverflow comment chain. You might be better to ask this question on the Jena users support list. Briefly: absolutely you should express your domain model in RDF, using RDFS or OWL as modelling languages. That is how you express the meaning - semantics - of your application model. SPARQL and SPARQL/update are technologies for querying or updating your data once it is available. That's quite a different concern from creating the domain model in the first place.